# How can I place an image on the centre of slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to place an Image on the centre of running slideshow on my website. Is there any way I can do that? Slideshow code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-->
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="One.jpg"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="Two.jpg"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="Three.jpg"

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<img src="One.jpg" name="slide" width="1500" height"1500">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var step=1
function slideit () {
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
if(step<3)
step++
else
step=1
setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}

slideit()
//-->
</script>
</center>
```

Comment: FYI the `<center>` tag was deprecated a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
.slideshow-div {
position: relative; 
z-index:1;

}
#image-class{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 200px;
    z-index:2;

}
```

where `slideshow-div` is the class of your slideshow container
and `image-class` is the class of your image.

http://jsfiddle.net/TDSFF/22/

This makes the image appear over the slide show..

Comment: Lal, thanks for response, but i don't understand what you mean by 'slideshow container'

Answer (score 0):

You can set parent div (in this case, body) to text-align: center; and display each of your slideshows as inline-block :

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

body img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```